# Protonation of nitric acid

Tags: electrochemistry

I found that reaction: HNO3 + 4.1633363423443E-17 H3O = NO2{+} + OH{-}
Please help me understand " 4.1633363423443E-17" term.

Comment: The title actually should be "*What does XXXX E YY formula mean?*" which would quickly leave this question off-topic.

Comment: Could you provide the reference where you saw this?

Comment: That come from http://www.webqc.org/balance.php when I tried to ballance the hypotetical reaction HNO3+H3O=NO2{+}+OH{-}

Answer (score 7):

It seems to me like you were asked to balance a chemical equation and you used some computer program to do it for you instead.

4.1633363423443E-17 is the result of the limitations of floating point arithmetic (ie that computers only have finite precision). The real answer should be 0 (which you could have figure out by balancing it yourself).